# How can i get an array value from PHP to JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can i get an array value from PHP to JQuery? And then just alert any one at jquery of array value get from PHP.... Any simple and complete example..?

Comment: Are you familiar with JSON?

Comment: same question gets asked here numerous times a week...did you try searching?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

use json_encode to encode your array in JSON format

```
echo '{"Data":'. json_encode($clients) .'}';
```

**Jquery**

you can use getJSON method to fetch the data and loop through it using $.each

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL+'/getPerkDetail.php?doc_id='+doc_id, function (data) {
    var ClientsAll = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(ClientsAll.Data, function() {

        var client_id = this.client_id;
        echo client_id;

    });
});
```